# Mount cloud storages (Dropbox/Gdrive) as virtual disk or virtual folder inside Windows file system (free alternative to Mountain Duck)

Tags: cloud-storage, google-drive, dropbox, filesystems, cloud

I need to mount clouds, like Dropbox or Gdrive either as a virtual disk or a virtual folder inside my Windows file system.

Requirements:

- Free.
- I'd like to mount at least 2 clouds with the same software.
- If it's a portable software, it's even better.
- If it allows multiple accounts for the same clouds, it's also even better (but not mandatory)

I'm looking for a free alternative to Mountain Duck, Netdrive, etc...

I tried to use Carotdav, but I'd like to try other software.

Comment: I can't judge the quality of the site, but when I'm looking for alternatives, I usually check this: [https://alternativeto.net/software/mountain-duck/](https://alternativeto.net/software/mountain-duck/)

Comment: Lolx ! Beat me to it (+1). the free stuff is at https://alternativeto.net/software/mountain-duck/?license=free

Answer (score 2):

https://www.raidrive.com/

I am using it for WebDAV, but it also supports common clouds storages.
Currently its free.

Comment: Welcome :-) Can you explain a bit more about how this answers the OP's question? Thanks

Comment: it supports gdrive and dropbox as windows "disk" which was the original question

Comment: Thanks, perhaps that will prod the OP to try it out and maybe award an answer (which would help others who view this question in future)

Answer (score 1):

Rclone.Org is all you need. You should mount cloud drives manually.

- Around 100 cloud storage providers supported.
- Free and open source.
- Well maintained with commits every few days: https://github.com/rclone/rclone
- Popular judging from the 40k GitHub stars.